# How to cite a repeatedly used direct quote?

Tags: citations

I am writing a seminar paper where I would like to reference one scholar's (A) view of another scholar's (B) work. This view (that scholar A holds) reoccurs throughout my paper.

Am I required to reference the quote every time I mention it, is it enough if I cite it the first time, or does it need to be cited in every section of the paper?

I am using the Harvard citation style.

**Example**:

> Scholar A describes Scholar B's theory as a "genealogical
>   constructivism with iterative descriptive connotations" (Scholar A
>   2007, p.8)

later in the text:

> Other authors subscribe to the "genealogical constructivism with
>   iterative descriptive connotations" movement.

Do I need a citation in the second reference?

Comment: Why not say something like this: _"Other authors subscribe to the Scholar A's (view on) OR (description of) OR (definition of) the Scholar B's theory"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure I'm in a different field, but I would say no, you don't, because you're just reusing the quote to describe something you already recalled and cited.  However, that seems like a mouthful, so I would suggest creating some shorthand for it, such as "genealogical constructivism perspective" or GCIDC perspective.  (In any case, look at other papers in your field for ideas, both regarding my suggestion and your original question.)